# AWS MSK - Internal Brokers communication

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, socketserver, aws-msk

I am using AWS MSK for our production workload and we have been noticing some not very clear log messages in cloudwatch. The messages are about the internal communication between brokers (more on cluster setup later):

```
[2022-05-14 06:50:17,171] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=2] Failed authentication with ec2-18-185-175-128.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/18.185.175.128 ([97fe8ff0-ee38-46c5-ae21-1545fd571224]: Access denied) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Our logs are cluttered with these recurring messages. The logs can be found on all three brokers, all referencing the `brokerId=2`, as per the message above.
I am assuming the instance referenced is one of the MSK brokers.

Whilst the logs are at INFO level and the cluster seems to work fine, I'd like to understand if anyone had to face these sorts of output messages before?

The MSK config is the following:

- 3 brokers over 3 availability zones
- encryption in transit,client_broker = TLS, encryption in cluster
- client_authentication sasl I am
- cluster properties: *auto.create.topics.enable = true, default.replication.factor = 3,    num.partitions = 3, delete.topic.enable = true, min.insync.replicas = 2, log.retention.hours = 168, compression.type = gzip*
- kafka version: 2.7.0

I would be interested to know how to get rid of this log message and if this should be a matter of worry.

Thanks,
Alessio

Comment: I feel like this question would be better suited for AWS support for fixing the problem rather than suppressing logs (which you'd do with Kafka's log4j properties, but I'm not sure you can edit that within MSK)

Comment: That's a good point. Although, I'd like to know what is generating that message before going off and suppressing the message itself.

Comment: Probably some IAM role between the machines? Hard to know. That's why I suggested creating an AWS support ticket

Comment: Yeah. I might as well go with that for the time being. It's really hard to say, as it's a managed Kafka cluster service from AWS. So I'd expect roles and networking to be ironed out by them Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Have the same issue and the support just sent me a link to the MSK IAM documentation (after TWO WEEKS of wait time). No help at all...

Comment: I have concluded that error only happens with the smallest instance type you get in MSK. Switching to the next instance type does the work. Although it's considerably more expensive. Not the best service from AWS IMO. @moritz.vieli